# Algorithm not increasing polynomially

Tags: algorithm, function, data-structures, time-complexity

Suppose I got a Sort Algorithm with n² Time. Now I should find any four functions which has less growing in function , but not polynomial less.

What is the approach to get there?

I think the solution would be n² -n^1,9 or n²/log(n) or n²/loglog(n) or n² /logloglog(n)
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think last three are correct, as the rate between each of them and n^2 is not polynomial, and actually asymptotic less than polynomial.
I also thinks that first one (n^2-n^1.9 if i read it correctly) isn't correct